# Richtig oder falsch: "Kann ich ihr fotografieren?"

Tags: verb, interrogative

> "Kann ich ihr fotografieren?" (Can I take your (a girl) photo?)

Ist die Frage ist richtig oder falsch?

Comment: Das ist eine Frage, die das Lexikon beantwortet" vtr, jemand(en)/etwas fotografieren.

Comment: Wenn du fragst, ob ein Satz richtig oder falsch ist, gib bitte an, welcher Teil Dir Probleme bereitet bzw. worüber Du unsicher bist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falsch. Es muss heißen

> Kann ich Sie fotografieren? (May I take your picture)

Comment: Entschuldigung, "Sie" is meaning "You". How can I say, "take Your photos".

Comment: Conveniently, _Sie_ refers to both a single person and a group (polite form). If you are on familiar terms, it would be "dich" (single person) or "euch" (group).

Comment: I agree. For the case of a you(polite form singular) I thought the possessiv pronomen Ihr (Your) may be used. Because it is about that person and her photo that I wish to take. Please clarify

Comment: _Ihr_ would be "your", but the German expression doesn't refer to the photo as such (ihr Foto = your picture) but the act of taking the picture instead (Darf ich Sie fotografieren = lit. may I photograph you).

Comment: Yes that clears the doubt. So any personal activity like..  "Ich liebe Sie Musik" (I like your Music ). "Ich moechte Sie lachen"(I like your laugh) are right ?

Comment: No. Firstly, music is not an activity :) Secondly, it is not about the personal aspect. It's just that the construction `to take one's picture` is not used in German and instead we say `to take a picture of something`. Your examples are something completely different and are translated to `Ich mag Ihre Musik / Ihr Lächeln`

Comment: No, it's _Ich liebe Ihre Musik_ and _Ich liebe Ihr Lachen_. Unfortunately this is not the venue to go into greater detail.

Comment: You are mixing up the different types of pronouns I'm afraid. "Ich liebe ihre/deine/seine/unsere/... Musik"

Answer (score 2):

Die deutsche Konstruktion ist "jemanden fotografieren", also beispielsweise

> Sie fotografiert ihn.

(She is taking his picture.)

The rest is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

When talking to a child, I would rather say:

> Darf ich ein Foto von dir machen?

This sounds very natural to me. The verb *dich fotografieren* sounds a little bit more formal, but only a little bit.